# Failed to execute 'send' on XMLHttprequest' - Sitecore

Tags: richtext-editor

We are using sitecore 7.2 with Coveo for sitecore(3.0). When I try to edit a rich text field for an item using EditHtml, I am getting this message below and not able to accept the changes.

Failed to execute 'send' on XMLHttprequest': Failed to load 'https://www.cm.instancename.com/sitecore/shell/~/xaml/sitecore.shell.applications.contenteditor.Dialogs.EditHtml.aspx?hdl=someGuid.

But when i try make changes using ShowEditor and use Design, the changes I made are accepted.

Can anyone help me to understand why this issue is occurring.

Comment: Could you please open the dev tools, switch to network tab and then see what is the response content of this request? Perhaps we could find something interesting there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your webservers operate behind a load balancer/proxy, SSL certificate is installed only on the load balancer/proxy and communication between load balancer/proxy and Sitecore is plain HTTP.

Client -> HTTPS -> Load Balancer/proxy -> ALWAYS http -> server

I am afraid Sitecore does not completely support this configuration. As far as I remember, some part of Sitecore does use context URL as a basis of generating/modifying URLs. Such configuration was not tested and is not officially supported. In this case, you may experience the following issues:
You will not be able to open a number of the Sitecore dialogs due to their iframe src value set to http://... .

Always include a server URL setting that cannot be used since it will generate the wrong URL.

So, full SSL appears to be a safe option for now.

Cliend -> HTTPS -> Proxy -> HTTPS -> Sitecore

You have to do this in IIS directly.

Following article may be helpful:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_hardening/configuring/increase_login_security